# Order confirmation PDF only for virtual products

Tags: pdf, virtual-products

I am about to sell tickets on my webshop, where I would like to attach a PDF. However I would only like to attach the PDF if the order contains the product type virtual products. In this way I make sure that people buying normal product will not receive a PDF.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you 'manually' send these PDF files (own/3rd party module).

You could loop through order items before sending the PDF of the order, checking for product type:

```
$sendPdf = false;
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
    if ($orderItem->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL) {
        $sendPdf = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($sendPdf) {
    // Send your PDF
}
```